# watir webdriver select_list element not visible error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am trying to select an option from a select list using watir-webdriver.

watir-webdriver gem version : 0.6.4
Ruby 1.9.3 on mac osx lion

HTML of the select list:

```
<select id="cc.expiryMonth" name="cc.expiryMonth">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
<option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option>
<option value="8">08</option>
<option value="9">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

The code i used is

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").options[4].select
```

I am getting error

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/_c/j__zdvw93gqgyyvzwmmgtwwr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130620-1023-1s8kag6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7736:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/_c/j__zdvw93gqgyyvzwmmgtwwr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130620-1023-1s8kag6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10437:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/_c/j__zdvw93gqgyyvzwmmgtwwr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130620-1023-1s8kag6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/_c/j__zdvw93gqgyyvzwmmgtwwr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130620-1023-1s8kag6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/_c/j__zdvw93gqgyyvzwmmgtwwr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130620-1023-1s8kag6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
  ./features/step_definitions/Wotif_FlightSearch_DOM_steps.rb:145:in `/^I enter all details on booking page$/'
```

Went through the watir-webdriver code in the gem library and exhausted all ways of selecting an option, all of them throw the same error.

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").focus
```

is successful, but selecting option throws element not visible error.
Also tried send_keys unsuccessfully.
Would appreciate any suggestions on how to handle this

**UPDATE:**

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").options[8].value
```

returns the value but

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").options[8].select
```

or

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").select @browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").options[8].value returns element not found error
```

Comment: Is the select element always visible or do you have to perform an action to make the select element visible? The html sample and code you tried works by itself, so there is something else about the page that is causing the failure.

Comment: its at the bottom of the screen and the webdriver is scrolling down there and settings other select_lists there successfully.....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue by following one of the other questions on stackoverflow where the suggestion is to use javascript to select the option in the select list.Nothing else worked.Happy that something worked finally

Comment: can you tell me the link and how you did it using java script in watir-webdriver

Comment: The link would be very useful. How do you use javascript from watir?

Comment: Sorry guys, the way to use javascript inside watir-webdriver code is to `@b.driver.execute_script('write your javascript code here')`

Answer (score 0):

did you try this :

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").select '04'
```

or even

```
b = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
s = b.select_list :name => 'cc.expiryMonth'
s.select '04'
s.selected_options
```

tell me what's up

Comment: Hi, Tried the option .select '04' option. Its throwing the same error element not visible error.Element is right there on the screen but webdriver fails to identify it.Tried sleep and waiting till it exists? and visible?

Comment: @rails4sandeep, there's is some wait yes, take a look [here](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timing issue. Try this:

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").options[4].when_present.select
```

More information at http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The execution is timed_out after the max timeout time when using the when_present method

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's more than one select list with this name on the page, and Watir-webdriver is waiting for the first element, but the one that's visible is actually the second one.

Give this a try:

```
 p @browser.select_lists(:name => "cc.expiryMonth").count
```

Does it return higher than 1 in the command prompt / mac equivalent?  If so you can use an index to select the one you want instead

```
@browser.select_list(:name => "cc.expiryMonth", :index => 1).select("04")
```